# Wrap vertical ao invés de horizontal

Tags: html, css

Quando o conteúdo de uma série de elementos HTML com *display inline* não cabe num *container* de tamanho fixo, o normal é que o conteúdo seja quebrado como texto. Isso é, da esquerda para a direita. Algo como:

```
div1 div2 div3 div4 div5 (quebra)
div6 div7 div8 div9 div10 (quebra)
div11 div12 div13...
```

Eu gostaria que, ao invés de fluir da esquerda para a direita, os elementos fluíssem de cima para baixo (como *display* em *block*)... Mas que ao preencher a altura do *container*, o conteúdo sofresse uma quebra e uma nova coluna fosse preenchida a direita. Algo como:

```
div1      div6      div11
div2      div7      div12
div3      div8      div13
div4      div9      ...
div5      div10
(quebra)  (quebra)
```

É possível fazer isso apenas com HTML e CSS? Meus elementos variam dinamicamente e eu gostaria de poder fazer algo que não envolvesse modificar o layout programaticamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a propriedade **[column-count](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-count.asp)** para definir a quantidade de colunas de seu *container*, exemplo:

```
<div class='wrap'>
    <div class='col'>div1</div>
    <div class='col'>div2</div>
    <div class='col'>div3</div>
    <div class='col'>div4</div>
    <div class='col'>div5</div>
...
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
-webkit-column-count: 3;
   -moz-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
 }
```

**Exemplo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2sT9/1/)**